# A picture of Gaspard Monge

Tags: cipher, story

In Paris, a famous Nobel prize winner was found murdered in his kitchen.
The door of the refrigerator stood wide open, and a small piece of butter
had fallen on the floor.  On the kitchen table, there were a French-English
dictionary, a mirror, a compass and a telescope.  The calendar on the wall
showed the page for April 2014, and next to the calendar there was a picture
of Gaspard Monge.  With his very own blood the dying scientist had written
the following numbers onto the kitchen floor: **28-27-57-16-26-3-58**.

The police narrowed the crime down to the following list of suspects:

> Antoine, Bastien, Camille, Dorian,
>    Etienne, Felice,  Gustave, Justine,
>    Ludovic, Mathieu, Nicolas, Ophelie,
>    Pauline, Quentin, Raphael, Suzanne,
>    Thibaut, Vincent, and Xavier.

Who murdered the Nobel prize winner?

Comment: I never understood why dying people write silly codes with their own blood. Surely it would make more sense to just write the killer's name?

Comment: I assume the double "of" in the title was just a typo, but do rollback my edit if it was actually a clue!

Comment: @Geobits: Blood is easily wiped away. If the killer had noticed the victim writing their name, he would have just wiped it off. Not to mention, blood quickly oxidates and crumbles due to the iron in it, and any message written thereof would fade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers 28-27-57-16-26-3-58 are the atomic numbers of Ni-Co-La-S-Fe-Li-Ce.
The Nobel prize was for chemistry, and the two killers were Nicolas and Felice.